# Flying to a Schengen zone from a country other than the one where the visa was issued

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen

If i have a Schengen visa issued by the German embassy in Qatar, can I fly to Germany from Lebanon? I heard that it's not allowed, but want to get a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't matter at all... visas are about where you go, not where you come from, and Schengen visas in particular are pretty flexible (you could enter France instead of Germany, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

As Flimzy pointed out, the Schengen visa will allow you to enter any Schengen country, unless it is a Limited Territorial Validity Visa (LTV). From [schengeninfo.com:](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/)

> This type of visa obtained allows you to travel only in the Schengen State that has issued the visa or in some other cases, in the certain Schengen States specifically mentioned when applying for the visa. Apart from these Schengen countries, this specific visa is invalid to any other Schengen country not specified prior. The holder of this type of visa cannot enter or transit through any other Schengen country that is not the first and final destination target. This type of visa is issued in very peculiar cases such as a humanitarian reason or under international obligation as an exception to the common USV system. This type of visa may apply for individuals who don’t possess a valid travel document yet have to travel to a Schengen area on an emergency of any kind.

The Schengen guidance also has no caveats on which country you travel from.

Comment: All true but the question is about the country you are flying *from*, not the country you are flying *to* (and it does not matter either, but the quote does not really address the issue).

Comment: I did originally have a  specific sentence in there to point out that it doesn't matter which country you fly from. Have updated it now.